# is there a way to force chrome to accept a self signed site?

Tags: certificates

I want to access to a site in which zimbra is installed, the address is like 'https://...', but when I try to access it from chrome on my phone I have a message telling me the connection is not secured. Is there a way to force chrome to accept the encryption?

thanks

olivier